# How to connect Websocket to android application or any 3rd party library is required?

Tags: java, android

How to connect Web socket API to android application or any 3rd party library is required? any know know this concept please post

Comment: It seems like you're looking for someone to write code for you. Please check out how to ask questions on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should at least show some effort - and code - and precisely tell us where you're struggling.

Comment: I am new in the web socket functionality.so,I don't have idea about Web socket program in android. That's why i posted in stack overflow, if you know means just explain otherwise no need your help.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not how stackoverflow works. Your question is way too broad. You need to come with a specific programming problem, show some code and tell us what's not working as expected.

Comment: you can find whole example [here](https://github.com/varvet/mobile-websocket-example).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [okhttp3](https://github.com/square/okhttp) on Android to handle WebSockets!

Example code:

```
public class EchoWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {
  @Override public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
    // called when the connection is opened
  }

  @Override public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
    //...
  }

  @Override public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
    //...
  }

  @Override public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason){
    //...
  }

  @Override public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response){
    //...
  }
}
```

Then, in your `Activity`:

```
@Override protected onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

  Request request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://echo.websocket.org").build();
  EchoWebSocketListener listener = new EchoWebSocketListener();
  WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);

  client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
}
```

Comment: this code disconects the app right after connecting.